# Why does an integer plus empty space plus string in Javascript result in sum of the number and string ? (2+ +'22' = 24)

Tags: javascript

Why does (2+ +'22') result in 24 rather than 222 as it would if it was (2+'22') in Javascript?

Comment: Because the [unary plus operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_()) attempts to convert its operand to a number.

Comment: `2 + + + + + '22'` results in the number 24 too. (Just a little something extra to think about once you understand `2 + +'22'`. You may also like to try `2 + +'aa'`.)

Comment: @nnnnnn Yeah I did try these once I understood the concept. ;)

Comment: @JamesAllardice thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code will execute like this when you use an [unary plus operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_()),

```
step 1: 2 + +'22' //string preceded by an 
                  //unary plus operator will be converted as a number.
step 2: 2 + 22
step 3: 24
```

Unary plus operator is having [highest precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) over addition operator. Hence it will be evaluated first as I said above.

Additionally if a string cannot be converted as a number by the unary operator then `NaN` will be returned.

Comment: "string followed by an" => "string preceded by an"

Comment: @Andy That's correct. I am a non native english speaker. ;)